# Xcode 11 GM - app crashes after startupon device Terminated due to signal 9

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a legacy app that uses Objective-C (with manual memory management). Using the new Xcode 11 (gold master) the app crashes after building and starting to run on the device/simulator. I noticed that this only happens to devices/simulators with iOS 12 or earlier. The crash happens after start up and I can get no exact pinpoint in the code when this happens.
There is no specific crash message only:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

Comment: Add crash logs in your question.

Comment: There is a GM2 which later on became the final stable release of Xcode 11.

Comment: I have same issue on one objective-c code. An application crash on specific case without any crash message. After digging i found that application crash because of one weak object reference. Change that object as strong property reference. And magic it's working. It's weird. But work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the subprojects were getting build with different deployment targets. When the deployment target is the same on all subprojects as the main project this crash goes away. 
The answer that got me on the right track is from this thread

[Xcode 8, iOS 8 simulator with crash: "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_unsafeClaimAutoreleasedReturnValue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486064/xcode-8-ios-8-simulator-with-crash-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-n)